# Why does this CSS gradient show up with the wrong colours in IE 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

So I am trying to put a gradient background on a table, via a class:

```
.prov-results-bkgrd {
    background: #fff url(/_images/prov-results-table-bg.jpg) left bottom repeat-x;

    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        from(#fff),
        to(#dedbd5)
    );

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #dedbd5);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#dedbd5');
}
```

IE8 and FireFox look OK. They apply the gradients as I thought: from white, to a light beige.

However, IE7 applies the gradient from *black* to a dark blue??? WTF is up with that...?

Where would that come from? Does IE7 not recognize the hex colors?

And if it didn’t, wouldn’t it apply the default background, i.e. `#fff` and the image file??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried with #ffffffff instead of #fff and #ffdedbd5 instead of #dedbd5 for the gradient filter (ie7) ?

You must specified alpha value I think
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532929(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 10):

IE does recognize hex colors, but not the kind you're using. Only those with 6 hexadecimals (#RRGGBB) or 8 hexadecimals (#AARRGGBB; only works in the gradient filter!) will work. It will also accept named colors.

So it will work if you replace the `#fff` by `white` or `#ffffff` (or `#ffffffff`, but that's longer than necessary in this case).

The MSDN pages for [startColorStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532930(v=VS.85).aspx) and [endColorStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532879(v=VS.85).aspx) also note that the default start color is blue, and the default end color is black, and:

> String input that is outside the hexidecimal range will revert to the default value.

Comment: The default start and end colors are blue and black???? Why on earth would that ever be a good idea?